# youtube video player fullscreen crashes

Tags: flutter, youtubeplayer

I am using this flutter plugin - youtube_player_flutter v7.0.0+7.

The player works fine on portrait mode but on clicking the full-screen icon it crashes. Please see the below code:

```
return YoutubePlayerBuilder(
      onExitFullScreen: () {
        
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(DeviceOrientation.values);
      },
      player: YoutubePlayer(
        controller: _controller,
        showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
        progressIndicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        onReady: () {
          _isPlayerReady = true;
        },
        onEnded: (data) {
//          _controller
//              .load(_ids[(_ids.indexOf(data.videoId) + 1) % _ids.length]);
          _showSnackBar('Next Video Started!');
        },
      ),
      builder: (context, player) => Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            widget.content.title,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            player,
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Exceptions?

Comment: No. Error messages or exceptions.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "crash"?

Comment: When the user clicks on the fullscreen icon, the player stops/crashes, not the app.